# Category comes under navigation menu "No" option is not coming in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created a separate module to display all categories, It is displaying only the category comes in navigation menu "yes" option, but not displaying navigation menu "no". I want to display all categories.

My code:

```
  <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
  <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
 <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
  <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was not tested... see if it works for you

```
<?php

$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url');

$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?= $_category->getUrl() ?>">
                    <?= $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I am getting fatal error Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category::getCollection().